# No puedo actualizar atributo de objeto

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy intentando actualizar el atributo de un objeto para un carro de compra, en donde el atributo a actualizar es `quantity`, pero cada vez que intento actualizar me crashea la app con el siguiente error `Uncaught TypeError: "quantity" is read-only` Mi codigo es el siguiente: (como dato estoy usando recoilJs para manejo de estados)

productPage:

```
    // React
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

    // Components
    import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
    import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

    // Recoil
    import { cart, sayHelloState} from '../../store';
    import { useRecoilState, useRecoilValue } from 'recoil';

    // Location state props
    import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

    // Style.sass
    import './style.sass';
    import { prettyDOM } from '@testing-library/dom';

    // Images
    const productImage = require('../../assets/images/product/product.png');

    const notify = () => toast("Wow so easy!");

    const ProductPage = () => {

        const addToCartToaster = () => {
            toast(' Wow lo añadiste al carrito!', {
                position: "top-right",
                autoClose: 5000,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined,
            });
        }

        const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
        const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
        const [cartArray, setCart] = useRecoilState(cart);
        

        const location = useLocation();
        const { state: data } = location;
        const { data:product } = data;

        const addToCart = () => {

            if(cartArray.length < 1) {
                console.log('entra 2')
                setCart((item) => [
                    ...item,
                    {
                        id: product.id,
                        title: product.title,
                        quantity: 1
                    }
                ])
            } else {
                cartArray.map((cartItem) => {
                    console.log('entro principal', cartItem)
                    console.log('product ', product.id)
                    if(cartItem.id === product.id) {
                        console.log('entra 1')
                        // AQUI ME FALLA
                        cartItem.quantity = cartItem.quantity + 1;

                    } else {
                        setCart((item) => [
                            ...item,
                            {
                                id: product.id,
                                title: product.title,
                                quantity: 1
                            }
                        ])
                    }
                })  
            }
        }
        

        const setCountHandler = () => {
            setCount(count + 1);
        }

        

        const removeCountHandler = () => {
            if(count === 0) return;

            setCount(count - 1);
        }

        return(
            <div className="product-page-wrapper">
                <div className="column-product">

                    <div className="column-title-product-container">
                        <div className="title-and-price">
                            <div className="made-for-text">
                                <p>MADE FOR Aging Skin</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="daily-mineral-title">
                                <h1>{product.title}</h1>
                                {/* <h1>Broad Spectrum</h1> */}
                            </div>
                            <div className="lower-text-title">
                                <p>Use if texture changes got you down and it's time to start anew.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="price">
                                <p>${product.price}</p>
                            </div>

                            <div className="amount-and-add-button-container">
                                <div className="quantity-button">
                                    <div className="negative-sign" onClick={removeCountHandler}><p>-</p></div>
                                    <div><p>{count}</p></div>
                                    <div className="positive-sign" onClick={setCountHandler}><p>+</p></div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="add-button" onClick={() => addToCart()}>
                                    <p>ADD TO BAG</p>
                                </div>

                                <ToastContainer />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div className="product-image-container">
                        <div className="product-image">
                            <img src={product.image}></img>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="column-description-product">
                    <div className="main-description-row">
                        <div className="description-container-container">
                            <h1>PRODUCT DESCRIPTION</h1>
                            <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam arcu orci, consequat et eros id, laoreet consectetur dui. 
                            Curabitur ac risus placerat, fringilla tortor in, porta purus. Donec feugiat tincidunt scelerisque. Cras elit ante, tempor vel sem eget, placerat gravida eros. Nunc tortor justo, consequat nec imperdiet at, aliquet eu libero.
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="net-weight-container">
                            <p>Net wt: 17 fl.oz / 50ml</p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="adversory-container">
                            <p>Non-toxic</p>
                            <p>|</p>
                            <p>Vegan</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }



    export default ProductPage;
```

En el store:

```
    import { atom } from 'recoil';

    export const sayHelloState = atom({
        key: 'sayHello',
        default: 'hello!!!'
    });

    export const cart = atom({
        key: 'cart',
        default: []
    });
```

Comment: Quantity es una propiedad de catarray. Por lo tanto estas tratando de modificar el estado directamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solucionado, lo que hice fue clonar el objeto para despues acceder al atributo y reasignarlo.

```
cartArray.map((cartItem) => {

            if(cartItem.id === product.id) {
           
                let newSetCart = cartArray.map((item) => {    
                    let cartItemCopy = {...item};
                    if(item.id === product.id) {
                        cartItemCopy.quantity = item.quantity + 1;
                    }
                    return cartItemCopy;
                
                });

                setCart(newSetCart);
            } else {
                cartArray.map((a) => {
                    if(a.id !== product.id) {
                        const newItem = {
                            id: product.id,
                            title: product.title,
                            quantity: 1
                        }
                        setCart(cart => [...cartArray, newItem]);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```